# Which airports in Ireland use Surface Movement Radar?

Tags: airport, radar

I know that Dublin uses SMR, but do any other airports in Ireland use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wording of this [IAA information](https://www.iaa.ie/air-traffic-management/technology/surveillance-radar) implies that it's Dublin only:

> The IAA also operate an Advanced Surface Movement Guidance and Control
>   System (ASMGCS), which facilitates the safe movement of aircraft and
>   airport vehicles at Dublin Airport, even during poor visibility
>   conditions. The ASMGCS incorporates Surface Movement Radar,
>   Multilateration and ADS-B.

There's a similar comment in [this document](https://www.iaa.ie/docs/default-source/misc/guide-to-air-traffic-operations.pdf). And the [AIP entry for Dublin](http://iaip.iaa.ie/iaip/Published%20Files/AIP%20Files/AD/EI_AD_2_EIDW_EN.pdf) mentions surface radar in the obstacles list, but the entries for [Cork](http://iaip.iaa.ie/iaip/Published%20Files/AIP%20Files/AD/EI_AD_2_EICK_EN.pdf) and [Shannon](http://iaip.iaa.ie/iaip/Published%20Files/AIP%20Files/AD/EI_AD_2_EINN_EN.pdf) (the [next busiest airports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_busiest_airports_in_the_Republic_of_Ireland)) don't.